# How to kill all MySQL processes in processlist?

Tags: mysql

I want to kill all the MySQL processes in the process list. Is there any way to do that?

```
# mysqladmin -u root -p processlist
Enter password: 
+------+----------------------+---------------------+----+---------+------+-------+------------------+
| Id   | User                 | Host                | db | Command | Time | State | Info             |
+------+----------------------+---------------------+----+---------+------+-------+------------------+
| 1908 | unauthenticated user | 192.168.1.103:46046 |    | Connect |      | login |                  |
| 1909 | unauthenticated user | 192.168.1.103:46047 |    | Connect |      | login |                  |
| 1910 | unauthenticated user | 192.168.1.103:46048 |    | Connect |      | login |                  |
| 1914 | unauthenticated user | 192.168.1.103:46049 |    | Connect |      | login |                  |
| 1946 | unauthenticated user | 192.168.1.103:46076 |    | Connect |      | login |                  |
| 1954 | unauthenticated user | 192.168.1.103:46078 |    | Connect |      | login |                  |
| 2015 | root                 | localhost           |    | Query   | 0    |       | show processlist |
+------+----------------------+---------------------+----+---------+------+-------+------------------+
```

Comment: Any reason you can't just stop and restart mysqld?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bulk or mass killing misbehaving MySQL queries](http://serverfault.com/questions/11357/bulk-or-mass-killing-misbehaving-mysql-queries)

Answer (score 4):

Looks like this might be covered at [Bulk or mass killing misbehaving MySQL queries](https://serverfault.com/questions/11357/bulk-or-mass-killing-misbehaving-mysql-queries)

Comment: then shouldn't you mark this as a dupe?

Comment: @chicks: This answer is seven years old ...

Comment: I should have noticed that the user was dormant.  Sorry Sven.  Since kenorb linked to the dupe in the comments it seems safe to delete this answer -- unless there is some guideline about preserving things over a certain age.

Answer (score 2):

Stop/start of MySQL instance is not an answer. In most cases it can take quite a lot of time and impact your production. You should just KILL such queries.

Two interesting articles:

[How to selectively kill queries in MySQL?](http://www.dbasquare.com/2012/04/04/how-to-selectively-kill-queries-in-mysql/)

and:

[Why do threads sometimes stay in ‘killed’ state in MySQL?](http://www.dbasquare.com/2012/05/15/why-do-threads-sometimes-stay-in-killed-state-in-mysql/)

Answer (score 0):

Quickest way is just to restart MySQL.  Otherwise you'll need to kill off each running process one by one (there's no killall in mysqladmin).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with a shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get the processlist and save it in a file
mysqladmin -u root -p"your password" processlist > fullproce

# Get the process ids of the processes in the "Sleep" state and save them in id.
# Adjust the grep to match the processes you want to kill.
cat fullproce |grep Sleep |awk -F " " '{print $2}' > id

for todos_id in `cat ./id`
do
  # Kill each id identified earlier.
  mysqladmin -u root -p"your password" KILL $todos_id ;
done

# Remove files
rm  fullproce
rm id
```

Comment: ahhh....english please

Answer (score -1):

This shell command may help to kill all sleep processes:

```
mysqladmin proc | grep Sleep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs -L1 mysqladmin kill
```